# Publishing a Google Apps Script web app that exposes an API for public consumption without anonymous access

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, publish, google-workspace

I'm trying to wrap my head around how the publishing options for Google Apps Script web-apps work. I have a GAS project that delivers a JSON API. I want other non G-Suite services to be able to call the web-app URL. I am on G-Suite enterprise and my GAS project is created in our GCP organization.

When I publish the web-app there are three options:

- `myself`
- `anyone in my organization`
- `anonymous`

For various reasons, I cannot use the `anonymous` and obviously `myself` option won't work. So I have to use the `anyone in my organization` option.

Now, when a human, logged into a G-Suite account that is in the organization, goes to my web-app URL it will work as expected.

I have another web-site, outside of my organization. I want that web-site to call the web-app URL. I know everything online says to use the `anonymous` option but I cannot.

So I am wondering what options I have. I had some ideas but not sure:

- Do something such that my web site server/account has a G-Suite account that is in the organization. That way, when the web server makes a call to the web-app URL it would look like its coming from a G-Suite account that is in the organization. Does that make sense?
- Make the call to the web-app URL and pass some token information that would tell GAS to allow access.

Are either of these possible? Or are any other ways possible?

Comment: Checkout Tanaike's guide: [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#taking-advantage-of-web-apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Yeah I read that but can't make sense of it. It sounds like if I pass an `Authorization` token, then my web-server can make the API call even though the web-app will be published to only organization?

Comment: If company policy prohibits you from giving anonymous access to the web app, then sending a password won't help you.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan That's right. 1.But where exactly will you get this token? 2.Who are the users of this external website? On a broader note, Consider posting to this [site](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) about how to convince your superiors to give access or get other solutions or how to deal with your situation

Comment: Your "web site server/account" does make sense; did you try using [`clasp`](https://github.com/google/clasp) on the server to work as the bridge from G Suite to the world?  If not `clasp`, you could certainly create your own utility using the G Suite APIs and your own credentials.  However, ⚠️are you sure you aren't violating your company's security by attempting to expose G Suite data to the world?⚠️

Comment: Have you already explored the use of OAuth?

Comment: @TheMaster Convincing security team is a DOA. I'm not sure what other solutions there are -- hence this post.

Comment: @Rubén How would that work? Can you connect the dots for me -- I'm not seeing it?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan [This is the relevant part](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#access-token-for-accessing-to-web-apps). Have you tried doing it this way, under the assumption that your app running server-side is run by you with the scopes required for the first web app?